# How to keep files permission during gitlab auto deployment?

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am trying auto deploy branch from `gitlab 11.06` to a staging server.Both gitlab server and staging server are `centos 7.4`

Below is the `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
stages:
  - deploy
deploy_staging:
  stage: deploy
  tags:
    - php
  script:
    /home/gitlab-runner/.local/bin/deploy.sh
```

`deploy.sh` as below:

```
#!/bin/bash
deploy_path="/var/www/html"
 cd $deploy_path
 git pull origin master
```

auto deploy works fine,but owner and permission of files changed.For example:

*before auto deploy:*
 `drwxr-xr-x  2 apache webadmin   77 Nov 19 8:41 phpmailer`

*After auto deploy:*
`drwxrwxr-x  2 gitlab-runner gitlab-runner   77 Nov 19 10:11 phpmailer`

**I need auto deploy,I need to keep files permisson too.**
How to keep files permission during auto deployment?Thanks in advance for any solution!

Comment: Do you want to preserve ownership (`apache/webadmin` user/group) or permissions (`drwxr-xr-x`)? Or both?

Comment: @phd,both ownership and permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`git pull` seems to replace files (it creates a new file and move it) instead of writing to existing files. Hence there is no way for it to preserve ownership — newly created files are created with the process ownership, `gitlab-runner/gitlab-runner` user/group. To fix that run `git pull` under different user using e.g., `sudo`. Either

```
sudo -u apache /home/gitlab-runner/.local/bin/deploy.sh
```

in the `gitlab-ci.yml` or

```
sudo -u apache git pull origin master
```

in the `deploy.sh`. Please don't forget that `sudo` asks for password so you have to [configure it](https://www.sudo.ws/man/sudoers.man.html) to run the command(s) without password.

To retain permissions try to set `umask 055` in `deploy.sh` before running `git pull`.

Comment: Ownership and permission are critical when I deploy to production server.Is there any solution to maintain complicated ownership and permission after auto deployment?

Comment: Run `sudo chown user.group file1 file2…` to change ownership if you have complex ownership requirements.

Comment: ,`sudo chown user.group file1 file2` in `gitlab-ci.yml` or in `/home/gitlab-runner/.local/bin/deploy.sh`?How can use `gitlab-runner` sudo `root`?

Comment: ps.can I run  `setfacl` in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53428566/how-to-use-getfacl-and-setfacl-to-backup-and-exactly-restore-files-and-folders-p) after `git pull`?